# How can I do a query that shows any row that have more than twice in the same table without using GROUP BY or COUNT

Tags: duplication

I want to select all same item that occurs in the same table twice without GROUP BY or COUNT sentence. How to write the query?

For example, if the table is:

```
City
---------
New York
Los Angeles
London
Washington
London
Peking
London
San Fransisco
New York
Tokyo
Dubai
```

The result set should be like that:

```
City
---------
New York
London
```

(because 'New York' occurs 3 times and 'London' occurs twice in the original table)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Does the table have a primary key or some other unique column that allows to distinguish two different rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as
(
select 'New York' as city from dual union all
select 'Los Angeles' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'Washington' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'Peking' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'San Fransisco' from dual union all
select 'New York' from dual union all
select 'Tokyo' from dual union all
select 'Dubai' from dual
)
select
  distinct city
from
(
  select
    city,
    row_number() over (partition by city order by null) as rn
  from
    data
) 
where
  rn > 1
;

CITY
-------------
London
New York
```

No GROUP BY, no COUNT.

But we have DISTINCT, ROW_NUMBER(), PARTITION BY, ORDER BY.

Is it simpler/better than?

```
with data as
(
select 'New York' as city from dual union all
select 'Los Angeles' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'Washington' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'Peking' from dual union all
select 'London' from dual union all
select 'San Fransisco' from dual union all
select 'New York' from dual union all
select 'Tokyo' from dual union all
select 'Dubai' from dual
)
select
  city
from
  data
group by
  city
having
  count(*) > 1
;
```

No, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a primary key (or some other unique column) in that table, e.g. `id` you can use:

```
select distinct c1.city
from cities c1
where exists (select *
              from cities c2
              where c1.city = c2.city
              and c1.id <> c2.id);
```

If you do not have such a column and you are using Postgres you could use the built-in `ctid` instead. For Oracle you could use `rowid`.

---

If you don't have a unique column and don't use Postgres or Oracle, you should really use `count()`, `group by` and `having` as that is the most efficient solution.